# Consider the inequality $\ \sigma(n)<n \log \log 2^m n$. If an odd primitive abundant$\ PA_i $ satisfies it, will all its multiples satisfy it too?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $$\ \sigma(PA_i)<PA_i \log \log 2^m PA_i,  (1)$$ where$\ PA_i\gg 2^m $, and as one increases, so does the other ($\ 2^m $ can locally grow a bit faster, but on the long run,$\ \lim_{n,m\to\infty}\frac{PA_i}{2^m}=\infty $, and anyway the ratio is always of several orders of magnitude). Let$\ k $ be any odd integer$\ >1 $. Does$\ (1) $ imply $$\ \sigma(kPA_i)<kPA_i \log \log 2^m kPA_i ?  (2)$$ My guess is yes, because from$\ (1) $ trivially follows$\ k\times \sigma(PA_i)<kPA_i \log \log 2^m PA_i $. Then, it should be clear that $\ \frac{\sigma(kPA_i)}{k\times \sigma(PA_i)}<\frac{\log \log 2^mkPA_i}{\log \log 2^m PA_i} $, given the condition on the growth of both$\ PA_i $ and$\ 2^m $, making the first ratio tend to$\ 1 $ faster, and since$\ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sigma(kPA_i)}{k\times \sigma(PA_i)}=1$ while$\ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\log \log 2^mkPA_i}{\log \log 2^m PA_i}=\infty$. Hence,$\ (1) $ implies$\ (2)$. But perhaps this is not enough? I'd be very grateful if you could help me.